# How to replace part of a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to replace a part of a string in Javascript

The following example should clarify what i mean

```
var str = "asd[595442/A][30327][0]";
var strToReplace = "30333";

var strDesiredResult = "asd[595442/A][30333][0]";
```

Basically it means the second area within the brackets should get replaced with another string

How to do that?

What i did so far is something like this :

```
var str = "asd[595442/A][30327][0]";
var regex = /asd\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/;
var arrMatches = regex.exec(str);
```

The string appears in arrMatches[2] correctly, and i could replace this. But what happens if in arrMatches[1] is the same string ?

Because it should only replace the value in the second bracket area.

Comment: and again a downvote on a question of mine in a short time - i've asked a total of 5 questions here on this platform and everyone of them got downvoted in the last couple days, at least provide an explanation ...

Comment: I think you were downvoted because your question is not very clear.

Comment: The question is extremely clear

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match the first `[....]` followed with `[` and capture that part into a group (that you will be able to refer to via a backreference), and then match 1+ chars other than `]` to replace them with your replacement:

```js
var str = "asd[595442/A][30327][0]";
var strToReplace = "30333";
console.log(str.replace(/(\[[^\]]*]\[)[^\]]*/, "$1" + strToReplace));

var strDesiredResult = "asd[595442/A][30333][0]";
console.log(strDesiredResult);
```

The `/(\[[^\]]*]\[)[^\]]*/` has no `g`modifier, it will be looking for *one* match only.

Since regex engine searches a string for a match from left to right, you will get the first match from the left.

The `\[[^\]]*]\[` matches `[`, then *any* 0+  chars other than `]` and then `][`. The `(...)` forms a capturing group #1, it will remember the value that you will be able to get into the replacement with `$1` backreference. `[^\]]*` matches 0+ chars other than `]` and this will be replaced.

**Details**:

- `(` - a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) start

  - `\[` - a literal `[` symbol (if unescaped, it starts a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))
  - `[^\]]*` - a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches zero or more (due to the `*` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html))
  - `]` - a literal `]` (outside a character class, it does not have to be escaped)
  - `\[` - a literal `[`
- `)` -  end of capturing group #1 (its value can be accessed with `$1` [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) from the replacement pattern)
- `[^\]]*` - 0+ (as the `*` quantifier matches zero or more occurrences, replace with `+` if you need to only match where there is 1 or more occurrences) chars other than `]` (inside a character class in JS regex, `]` must be escaped in any position).

Comment: this is really sick ;)it looks like it works and beside your explanation i've no idea why this works, but i'll try to understand this for future things - thx dude

Comment: Please let me know what is unclear. The point I was making is that you need to rely on a `[^...]` construct, a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any char but those defined in the class. If you use `.*` or even `.*?`, the `.` can match `[` and `]`, and overmatch, or result in an incorrect match.

Comment: the reason why i said i've no idea whats going on is because i'm absolutely inexperienced in this kind of regex world - but i'm certainly willing to study this masterpiece ;)

Comment: I will add a full pattern explanation in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
'asd[595442/A][30327][0]'.replace(/^(asd\[[^\[\]]+\]\[)([^\[\]]+)(\]\[0\])$/, '$130333$3')
```

Test [here](http://regexr.com/3frnh)

```
^            - match beginning of string
first group  - match "asd[", any chars except [ and ], "]["
second group - match any chars except [ and ]
third group  - match exactly: "][0]"
$            - match end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One possible pattern is

```
str.replace(/^(.+)(\[.+\])(\[.+\])(\[.+\])$/, `$1$2[${strToReplace}]$4`)
```

You can see that `$<number>` is referred to captured string from regex (string groups in parentheses). We can refer to those and rearrange it however we want.

Comment: This won't help if there are more than 3 `[...]` substrings in the input string.

Comment: Then you can use this pattern instead `/^(.+)(\[.+\])(\[.+\])(.*)$/`. That's why I said there are many ways. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression like this `/\[[0-9]+\]/` as below.

```js
var str = "asd[595442/A][30327][0]";
var strToReplace = "30333";

var strDesiredResult = str.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/, '[' + strToReplace + ']'); 

console.log(strDesiredResult);  //"asd[595442/A][30333][0]";
```